# Fetch value from a set object in java

Tags: java

I'm iterating a set object to find a particular value. Is there any short way to fetch instead of iterating it? Here is my code

```
for(Tree t : assignedTrees) {
     println t.treeName;
}
```

The above code will return the expected value.

assignedTrees is the set object

```
Set<Tree> assignedTrees = new HashSet<Tree>()
println assignedTrees will return 
[Tree{id=null, treeName=Mango}]
```

Can I fetch the treeName instead of iterating?

Comment: With Java 8 you can use Lambda Expression to achieve this, they are pretty handy, give them a try! The [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) has an example similar to yours!

Comment: Possibly you could override `Tree.toString()` to return `Tree.treeName`

Comment: @Aravind, toString is already there

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch an object from a set by calling `mySet.get(object)`.  However, in your case you wish to fetch an object based on one of its attributes.  The best way to do this is with a map - e.g.

```
Map<String, Tree> trees = new HashMap<>();
trees.put(treeObject.treeName, treeObject);

Tree myTree = trees.get("myTreeName");
```

Note that if you're putting your own objects into sets or maps, you **must** override the equals and hashcode methods, or very strange things will happen.

Comment: "must override the equals and hashcode methods" - this is not true. You do not have to. You must override `hashcode` *in case you override* `equals`.

Comment: Honestly, I would really prefer Lambda Expressions as @BackSlash said in his comment.

Comment: If you do not override equals and hashcode, then two Tree objects with the same name and the same id will not always be considered equal, since they will only be compared on object references.  This could be the desired behaviour, but usually it's more helpful to compare objects based on attributes.

Comment: Well, two guys both named "Peter" are not equal, right? You are right provided two trees with the same name are equal, which might not be true.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use lambda to find any/first element that fullfils any condition. For example:

```
Set<Integer> coolStrings = new HashSet<String>();
coolStrings.add("HEHE")
coolStrings.add("NOPE")
coolStrings.add("JP2GMD")
coolStrings.add("1234")

try{
    String nice = 
    coolStrings.stream().filter(
        (str) -> { return str.equals("JP2GMD") || 
            str.equals("2137"); }
        }).findFirst().get();
    )
    System.out.println("Yay, i found a REALLY cool string! : " + nice);
}
catch(NoSuchElementException e){
    System.out.println("Not even one awesome string was found :(");
}
```

It will print "JP2GMD"

(I didn't compile it, there might be some minor syntax errors)

Working with [Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) class is extremally handy (as for java standards)